# Find underlying application using MSEdgeWebView2

Tags: windows-11, microsoft-edge

Even since Microsoft has introduced the [MSEdge Viewer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/), I have been inundated with various 3rd party apps running it, sometimes consuming resources in excess of what I want, or accessing weird Internet hosts.

I have already disabled Windows widgets, but don't want to all-out disable MSEdge Viewer, in case it's used to display something important in an app that I do need.

The question is, is it possible to find the underlying app using MSEdge Viewer, short of closing every app one by one and seeing what happens, or trying to guess according to the hostname it contacts? For example, Adobe Photoshop uses MSEdge Viewer, but I see no indication of what in the process details.

I am using Windows 11 Pro, build 22621.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to find the parent process of any window by using the free
[Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

Once the window is displayed, open Process Explorer and drag the bullseye
icon
[image]
and drop it over the window. The owning process will automatically
be selected in Process Explorer, so you can examine the properties
of the process and its parent(s).

Comment: Hi, thanks for reminding me about Process Explorer! Finding out the PID for Edge Viewer was never actually an issue, and it does not appear to run as a child process. However, Process Explorer shows the full command used to run Edge Viewer, which happened to show the culprit in my case – cFosSpeed.